# Preserve newlines when using php split

Tags: php

I'm using php's split function to break a pipe delimited record into an array

```
explode("|",$line)
```

When there is a newline within the pipe field, split puts it into a new array field

```
blue|is my favorite|color
```

works fine and gives 3 array elements

```
blue|is my
favorite|color
```

results in 4 array elements

How do I make it retain newlines?

Comment: Will you post the associated code you are working with, maybe the error is somewhere else, it is obviously not with explode()

Answer (score 2):

Splitting a string on `|` using [`explode()`](http://www.phpexplode.com/) will not affect newlines.

The only way you will get 4 elements in the resulting array is if there is a `|` at the start or end, which result in an array member with a blank string. You can drop these with [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and [`array_pop()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) respectively.